# Do you know the Chinese character which is formed by 王 on the left and 力 on the right?

Tags: word, characters

I can't evey type this word out, because I do not know how to pronouce it. I notice this word when seeing it in the name of an actor for a TV drama, then I thought it to be 功，but it turned out it was not 工 on the left but 王, then I checked Xinhua Dictionary but couldn't get the answer.

Comment: Use microsoft pinyin and type "uwangli", and, you can type it.

Answer (score 3):

玏  http://www.zdic.net/z/1e/js/738F.htm

Pinyin: lè

> 基本字义 (basic meaning)
>
> See : 瑊 http://www.zdic.net/z/1e/js/744A.htm
>
> 瑊 - 似玉的美石 (jade-like gemstones)

康熙字典 (Kangxi Dictionary)

[image: 玏]

> 本作。[image] 也。今省作玏，謂石之次玉者。
>
> Original character: [image]. Now simplified as '玏'.  It means "lesser gemstones that is similar to jade"

**Note:**

*In my opinion, naming a child '玉' emphasis his or her nobleness and being precious--(賈寶玉 is a good example).  Some modest people might feel that is too boastful, opt for the more humble word  '玏' instead. wishing the child will has noble-like quality, but can also relate to the common people.*

Comment: Don't you think it weird for one who name himself with a word that cannot even be found in Xinhua Dictionary and what does he want?

Comment: 玏 is an archaic character, it might be more common in ancient time, but no longer has any practical usage in modern Chinese. A father in contemporary time named his son 玏 is either very knowledgeable in ancient literary, or deliberately  looked for weird character from dictionary in order to give his son an extremely unique name.

Answer (score 2):

It is [玏](http://www.zdic.net/z/1e/js/738F.htm) (lè ㄌㄜˋ), means

> 似玉的美石 [jewel-like stone]